# iMessage on old iPhone

Tags: iphone, messages

So in the past few days I just retired my old iPhone 5 and upgraded to the new iPhone 6.

Once I took the SIM out, I expected just standard carrier calls and texts to stop working (for obvious reasons) but for some reason all forms of iMessage seem to have stopped working too.

For many reasons I intend on still using the iPhone 5 without a SIM so is they're any reason as to why iMessage stopped working? I thought it would have assumed the functionality of what would essentially be a very large iPod touch.

Enabling and disabling it in settings hasn't done much, yet it is activated successfully upon turning it on. I don't receive messages anymore and sending messages causes it to instantly fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the 8.0.2 iOS uodate, for some unknown reason my iPhone 5 got sent into recovery mode and I was forced to restore it from a backup since nothing I tried could get it out of recovery mode.

After restoring the phone, iMessage seemed to work once again allowing me to use the phone number as a means of communication and set it as the default.

Maybe this is because when getting the phone out of recovery, before I could restore I had to insert my sim from my iPhone 6 inside it to activate the phone. Maybe this had something to do with it. A message also appeared on my iPhone 6 and Mac when iMessage started working so perhaps that had something to do with it.

Anyway, it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to Apple's attempt to make it so that if you are moving from iOS to Android other iOS users can still message you as your iMessage will be disabled.

I managed to get a friend's phone to work by sending him an iMessage to his Apple ID. This seemed to fix it and now he can send/receive messages with others too.

Comment: Awesome. Got a friend to so that quickly and I can send again! We just discovered though messages to my mobile number don't go to my old phone and to my new phone only. Is there any way to get messages to my mobile to go to both or is this where I'll have to make do and draw the line

Comment: @SteppingHat This should be happening already. On your old device, go to Settings > Messages and check your phone number has a check mark next to it in the Send & Receive list.

Comment: Hey my mobile is back! Just had to check it again and its all sweet. Although it's not letting me select start new conversations from the mobile. It's not greyed out but when I tap it it does nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm even more odd. There are two options for my mobile number. Both are the same but one is greyed out and another is selectable. The selectable one also unchecks itself after a while too

Comment: @SteppingHat Try rebooting the phone?

Comment: Lost the selectable one now. Just the greyed out one and its unselected. Tried sending a test message to the phone again but it didn't do anything this time

Comment: if it doesn't have a sim, it doesn't have a phone number... if anything at all is going to work, only iMessages to/from your email address would have any hope, I would assume

Comment: @Tetsujin iMessages sent to my phone number also end up on my iPad and Mac (neither of which have a SIM) because I am receiving iMessages sent to my phone number on all three devices.

Comment: you have a point

Comment: I always thought that if there is an active phone assigned to iMessage, all devices can use that number. since I have a Mac this has been the case for me